# Reference a XML type in a XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Given the following XML I want to reference the different exercises by their type:

```
<root>
    <exercises type="foo">
        <text></text>
    </exercises>
    <exercises type="bar">
        <audio></audio>
    </exercises>
</root>
```

I would set this up like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!-- xml def -->
<xs:element name="root">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="exercises" type="foo-exercises"/>
        <xs:element name="exercises" type="bar-exercises"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But how do I explicitly check for the "type" definition in the given xml? That is, that the elements are of the given type? That is, that the given types are checked against the corresponding definition?

---

Edit:
I put it oddly: My problem is, to reference the "type" / attribute not in the type definition but in the reference to the fields.

Say: I want to check, whether there actually are 3 elements of type foo and 2 elements of type bar. So exercise is not descriptive enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this kind of element definition can not be achieved with XML Schemas.
In other words, you can not bound an element content model to a particular value of an attribute on this element (or in any other element).

Such control can be achieved with [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) for example.

Comment: Thx a lot for that clarification as well as the link to Schematron for example. This helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you this schema ..

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="exercises" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" type="exercise"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="exercise">
        <xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="foo">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="exercise">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="text" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="bar">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="exercise">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="audio" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

this is the related xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <exercises xsi:type="foo">
        <text></text>   
    </exercises>
    <exercises xsi:type="bar">
        <audio></audio> 
    </exercises>
</root>
```

In this way you used an xsd extension. [See here the reference](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_extension.asp)

Comment: thx for the fast answer. But I probably put it wrong. I really want to check for the type in the schema. Say I want to have a xs:choice in root with a validity check for 2 foo-exercises and 3 bar-exercises.
I will update that in the description. Sorry for not specifying properly.

Comment: Both elements of `root` must have the same `name` (exercises)?

Comment: yes. that is the issue actually. that was a xml format agreed upon quite some time ago and there is no way to change it now.

Comment: Your XSD is syntactically correct but when you tried an XSD validation of an XML fails. `Multiple elements with name 'exercises', with different types, appear in the model group` .. Anyway if you use mine XSD you could try to use XSD1.1 and assert between element [See here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/)